# Change href value according to child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the href value according to the child background-image value but when I change the background-image value than all href take a same value according to first div.

```
    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">                          
       <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom-20">                     
            <a href="" class="over">
                <div class="fill bg-change" style="background-image:url(images/cA4aKEIPQrerBnp1yGHv_IMG_9534-3-2.jpg);"></div>
            </a>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-3 col -->
    <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom-20">
       <a href="" class="over">
          <div class="fill bg-change" style="background-image:url(images/J3URHssSQyqifuJVcgKu_Wald.jpg);"></div>
       </a>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-3 col -->
    <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom-20">
       <a href="" class="over">
          <div class="fill bg-change" style="background-image:url(images/cA4aKEIPQrerBnp1yGHv_IMG_9534-3-2.jpg);"></div>
       </a>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-3 col -->
    <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom-20">
       <a href="" class="over">
           <div class="fill bg-change" style="background-image:url(images/J3URHssSQyqifuJVcgKu_Wald.jpg);"></div>
       </a>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-3 col -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.over').attr('href',function(e){
     var bg_img = $('.fill').css("background-image");
     bg_img = bg_img.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '');
     return bg_img;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.over').prop('href', function () {
    return $(this).find('.fill').css('background-image').replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '');
});
```

This iterates over each of the `.over` elements, and updates the `href` property to the processed string found in the `background-image` property.

It's worth noting that I haven't verified the results of the regular expression, and simply copied that part from your own posted code (given that it seems to work, or isn't mentioned in your question as *not* working).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).